# python - win32com excel not visible

Tags: python, excel

I have problem with using win32com.
When I use Word or Powerpoint(NOT EXCEL), They pop up (with no page).

```
import win32com.client
Word = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Word.Application")
Word.Visible = True
```

But using EXCEL, it does not work. 
and even on the Task Manager, Excel is not visible.

```
import win32com.client
Excel = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
Excel.Visible = True
```

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Also when I code more, another problem pops up.

```
wb = Excel.Workbooks.add()
ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

```
raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (repr(self), attr))
AttributeError: '<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library.Workbooks instance at 0x63711088>' object has no attribute 'add'
```

What is the problem? Please help me! T.T

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your issue with `Excel.Visible = True`. But I notice that you report `Process finished with exit code 0` which indicates that the interpreter has exited. After that happens, your COM client disappears and so will Excel. Try this interactively in PythonWin or IDLE instead.

Your problem with this line:

```
wb = Excel.Workbooks.add()
```

is that the VBA method is actually called `Add` not `add`. You have set up early binding using `gencache`. That has the advantage that you can get Intellitype-like hints, but has the disadvantage that you no longer have COM's case-insensitive late-binding lookup.

Comment: Thank you. I use `Excel.Visible = True` code on IDLE, and it works. But when i code it on Pycharm, the problem comes out. Only very short time(0.1s?) the Excel blinks and quit itself. Not on the background, it just gonna quit.

Comment: But Word or Powerpoint works well. Do you know what the problem is?

Comment: I don't have a copy of PyCharm handy. What you report doesn't happen if I simply run your code under `python.exe`: the Excel that the code starts up continues to run after the interpreter exits. Ditto Word. So it is clearly nothing to do with `win32com` or what you are doing. It may be that the Excel COM server is differently written from Word's, or it may be that PyCharm is doing something clever.